# How do I compose a set of sets that all match on one variable element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a collection of $N$ sets. Each set $n_i \in N$ is comprised of exactly $I$ elements $\{i_1, ... ,i_I\}$, where each $i_i \in J, J > I$. For any two sets $n_a$ and $n_b$, $n_a \cap n_b = \{i_j\}$ for some $i_j \in J$.

In other words, any pair of sets in $N$ share exactly one element, which could be a different element per pair.

For example, given $N = 55$ and $I=8$, what is the smallest $J$ that fits the above criteria?

Intuitively I think there is a way to calculate a minimal $J$ for an arbitrary $N$ and $I$, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Can it be done?

Comment: $I$ and $J$ are the sizes of two sets - $I$ being the size of any of the sets found in $N$, and $J$ being the size of the set that contains all the possible elements that make up a single set in $N$. So I think I am treating them as numbers. (Apologies for my notation in the above question; I am happy to make suggested improvements.)

Comment: The statements $i_i\in J$ and $i_j \in J$ could be clarified. Is $J$ the subset of natural numbers from $1$ to $J$ in this context?